# Xcode - PSMultiValueSpecifier

Tags: ios, xcode, settings

I wanna implement a PSMultiValueSpecifier in my App, so Users can change the Animation of iCarousel. I tried a lot now, but i can't figure out the right code (for my ViewController.m) ..

Maybe you can help me with that..

I wanna have something like that:

```
if(value 1 clicked) {
self.photoCarousel.type = iCarouselTypeRotary;
}
elseif(value 2 clicked){
self.photoCarousel.type = iCarouselTypeCylinder;
}
```

... and so on ( i have 6 values).

I really hope, you can give me the code, so i can implement it

My root.plist you can see here:

[image: root.plist.png]

Comment: This is a question about development so is odd topic here. It should be on Stack Overflow, however I suspect they will want to see more working about showing exactly what you do not understand rather than just asking for the solution code.

Answer (score 0):

I load the default value with this code:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults registerDefaults: [self initialDefaults]];
```

But i don't know, how to write an if-query to check which value is actually chosen, or which action my program should do then. I hope you understood my question, my english ins't the best, i'm sorry.

It's my first work with the settings.bundle.